# codeigniter with Highcharts- data not coming controller to view

Tags: php, codeigniter, highcharts

I tried to add highcharts library to my CI project. so I tried db query in my controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class ChartController extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct() {

       parent::__construct();

       $this->load->database();

    } 


    public function index()

    {

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(numberofclick) as count FROM demo_click 

            GROUP BY YEAR(created_at) ORDER BY created_at"); 

        $data['click'] = json_encode(array_column($query->result(), 'count'),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);



        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(numberofview) as count FROM demo_viewer 

            GROUP BY YEAR(created_at) ORDER BY created_at"); 

        $data['viewer'] = json_encode(array_column($query->result(), 'count'),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);



        $this->load->view('my_chart', $data);

    }

}
```

then i tried to access via view. and I placed the following code to check output of the controller.

```
<?php
 echo var_dump($this->_ci_cached_vars);
?>
```

then I am getting, following output with NO VALUES. what is the issue?

```
array (size=2)
  'click' => string '[]' (length=2)
  'viewer' => string '[]' (length=2)
```

Comment: Hi @Tharindu ucsc, You have used `highcharts` tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about data. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a demo with hard-coded, exemplary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this happens because you're returning set of objects instead of arrays. Since `array_column()` expects first parameter to be array, try to change `$query->result()` to `$query->result_array()` on each `$data` :

```
public function index()

{

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(numberofclick) as count FROM demo_click 

        GROUP BY YEAR(created_at) ORDER BY created_at"); 

    $data['click'] = json_encode(array_column($query->result_array(), 'count'),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);



    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(numberofview) as count FROM demo_viewer 

        GROUP BY YEAR(created_at) ORDER BY created_at"); 

    $data['viewer'] = json_encode(array_column($query->result_array(), 'count'),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);



    $this->load->view('my_chart', $data);

}
```